# Alternating series test for convergence, question about specific condition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

First a relevant excerpt from the textbook I am using:

Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence whose terms satisfy, for some positive integer $N$,

i) $a_na_{n+1} < 0$ for $n\geq N$,

ii) $\vert a_{n+1}\vert \leq \vert a_n\vert$ for $n\geq N$, and

iii) $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$.

Then the series $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges.

I understand what the theorem says, and how to use it, but I have a question about the third condition in the theorem. Say you have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt(n)}$ so that $a_n = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{\sqrt(n)}$. At first glance it seems one can apply the quotient rule, and take $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = \frac{lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(-1)^{n-1} }{lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt(n)}$$
However, since $(-1)^{n-1}$ constantly changes sign as $n$ approaches infinity, it seems this limit does not exist. I tried solving it in WolframAlpha, and at first glance it says that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n = 0$, but when I check the step-by-step solutions, the answer is actually $\frac{(undefined)}{\infty}$. Since the numerator in $a_n$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ it makes intuitive sense that the limit tends to $0$, but I don't know how to justify this mathematically. Are there any theorems that justify this ? I would greatly appreciate any input ! The solution manual to my textbook, in the specific example above, simply states that all the conditions are fulfilled without explanation.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking things. Look back at the epsilon-delta definition of converge (to zero); we only deal with the absolute value of the terms of the sequence, so the sign can be disregarded entirely. At this point the numerator is a constant 1 and all problems vanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saying something formal, think in this way, which is similar to what you wrote: $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ but alternating the sign at each $n$. Since $\frac 1{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow 0$ it should be clear that also $\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow 0$.

---

However, we need a proof. Simply note that for every $n\geq 1$
$$
0< \left|\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}},
$$ 
thus the thesis follows from the squeezing theorem for sequences.

Comment: So just to confirm that I understood you correctly, we get $\frac{-1}{\sqrt(n)} \leq \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt(n)} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt(n)}$ and then apply the squeeze theorem? If so then thanks for making me realize how easy this actually was :)

Comment: @ThomasFjærvik: yes, you correctly understood.